# ASP.Net 5 rc1 Localization in Views

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core

I need to have some strings given from resource file in my views. In Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddViewLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

and:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture("ru-RU"));
```

View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer loc
```

I read in the MSDN blog the following:

> The `IViewLocalizer` is an `IHtmlLocalizer` service that looks for a
>   resource based on the current view name.

So how should I name `.resx` files so that my localized strings appear in my view? If I've got `Views/Manager/Index.cshtml` then `Resources/Manager/Index.cshtml.ru-RU.resx` is correct? But the resource isn't been found...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is pretty confusing in the documentation, because the resource name is not based on the current view name, but on the current view path:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Localization/ViewLocalizer.cs
(line 101)

This means resource name should be named like this:

```
Views.{ControllerName}.{ViewName}.cshtml.{culture code}.resx
e.g. Views.Home.About.cshtml.de-DE.resx
```

I already reported this behavior a month ago: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3376

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me get the thing work. I agree, the way it works is not very handy yet. Hope they'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a base resource file simply called `resources.resx` which will be your 'fall-back' resource in case there isn't a translation for the selected language.

Each language resource file should then be named in the following format:

> resource-**culture-code**.resx

The culture code can be either the neutral language, or region specific language.

For example

- Spanish: resource-es.resx
- US English: resource-en-US.resx
- etc

When you set the UI culture of the Thread, the correct resource for the culture will be automatically used.

Answer (score 0):

Localization (I mean getting localized strings from resx files with Culture postfix) unavailable by launch application from Visual Studio. Need launch application from command line (e.g `dnx web`).

[Related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/153), topical for rc1